# How to write correctly this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I have a simple question about an algorithm. I'm not an algorithmic specialist and I need some help to write a particular one.

I will stay a bit "schematic" because I know that my algorithm will stop and that it is valid (I still have to formally prove it, but anyway), I just need to know how to write it correctly and efficiently.

The idea is the following :

---

**Initialization :**

I have two input variables $a_{0}$ and $b_{0}$ and I set $c_{0} = \min \{a_{0}, b_{0}\}$.

**Treatment :**

IF $a_{0} = b_{0}$, THEN STOP (*output variable* : $c_{0}$)

OTHERWISE $a_{1} = \min \{c_{0}, f(c_{0})\}$, $b_{1} = \min \{c_{0}, g(c_{0})\}$, $c_{1} = \min \{a_{1}, b_{1}\}$

IF $a_{1} = b_{1}$, THEN STOP (*output variable* : $c_{1}$)

OTHERWISE $a_{2} = \min \{c_{1}, f(c_{1})\}$, $b_{2} = \min \{c_{1}, g(c_{1})\}$, $c_{2} = \min \{a_{2}, b_{2}\}$

*etc.*

until a certain $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (which **exists**, as I said, it is not the point here), where $f$ and $g$ are some mappings.

---

My problem is that, obviously, I cannot know the step $n$ where the algorithm must stop and that it is not well written here...

I tried to write it in that way, can you tell me if it is correct ?

---

**Initialization :**

Two input variables $a$ and $b$

$c = \min \{a, b\}$

**Treatment :**

WHILE $a \neq b$

$a := \min \{c, f(c)\}$

$b := \min \{c, g(c)\}$

$c := \min \{a, b\}$

ENDWHILE

STOP (*output variable* : $c$)

---

I apologize in advance if the different terms (IF, WHILE, etc.) are not well used and I hope you'll understand the idea.

Thank you !

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It's hard to analyze the code without knowing that.

Comment: That looks like perfectly good pseudocode to me. It should work in any language, as long as you know enough about $f$ and $g$ to know that it will terminate. The output will be a point where $f$ and $g$ agree, If this is floating point computation you might have to worry about roundoff error. So I don't really know what you are asking us to do here.

Comment: Acutally, I just want to know if the way of writting it is good or not. First, I'm not 100% sure that what I wrote in second is the "same" as what I wrote first (that's the main question). Second, I don't really know if there are some "standards" to write algorithms in general, for example : I just write between parenthesis "output variable : $c$", is there a way of writting it properly ?

Comment: Ditto what @EthanBolker said.  I'd only add that I'd put a counter in the loop and a "sanity check" to quit after a million (or whatever), just in case $a=b$ doesn't occur. And, like Ethan said re roundoff, check for $abs(a-b)<1.0e-10$, or something along those lines.

Comment: Actually, I work with a finite number of possible values which are between $0$ and $1$ (for $a$ and $b$). So, without going to much into details, after a finite number of itterations, the algorithm will give (as an output) $c = 0$ (if it doesn't stop before of course).

Comment: (I know that this is not obvious because I don't explain the forms of $f$ and $g$)

Comment: @deeppinkwater Re your comment, sounds like you've never coded before. Just go for it. Not like the building will burn down if it doesn't work. And maybe try very simple $f,g$ functions first; functions that you easily know the answers for. When that works, then code your actual $f,g$.

Comment: There are no rules for the "correct" way to write algorithms informally. Check this wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode If you are writing that algorithm for a reader you might want to show a worked example.

Comment: Okay, thank you ! About my first remark (in the first comment), are we agree that the two "algorithms" I wrote are the same (in the sense that they will work in the same way and will give the same output at the end) ? As mentionned by @JohnForkosh above, yes, I never coded before (that's why I'm not sure about how to use for example the element WHILE here).

Comment: @deeppinkwater Yes, it looks to me like _" they will work in the same way"_. But like I suggested, >>first<< choose some real simple $f,g$ functions that you know (can infer/prove) the correct answer for, and program those. And debug your loop  using those. Once that works correctly, then use the actual $f,g$ you're interested in.

Comment: Okay, I will try... Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

### I think you meant to perform a while loop, but you needed an iteration index, I would propose the following:

**Initialization :**

Input variables $a_{0}$ and $b_{0}$,  and set $c_{0} = \min \{a_{0}, b_{0}\}$, a tolerance $\varepsilon>0$ and an index $k=0$.

**Treatment :**

While $|a_{k} - b_{k}| > \varepsilon$:

$\,\,\,\,a_{k+1} = \min \{c_{0}, f(c_{0})\}$

$\,\,\,\,b_{k+1} = \min \{c_{0}, g(c_{0})\}$

$\,\,\,\,c_{k+1} = \min \{a_{1}, b_{1}\}$

$\,\,\,\,k=k+1$

(End of while loop)

Return $c_{k}$